# Computing the differential in local coordinates

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential

Let $F:M\to N$ be a smooth map between manifolds and $p\in M$. I am having trouble understanding the differential $dF_p$. I understand how $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},..., \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right\}$. is a basis of $T_pM$. So we only really care where $dF_p$ maps basis elements. After a long string of calculations we showed that $dF_p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})=\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$. But where are the $F^j$ coming from? As far as I know, we only started with one smooth function $F$. I thought I would try an example so I tried it with the Hopf map $F:S^3\to S^2$ defined by $F(x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4)=(2(x^1x^2+x^3x^4),2(x^1x^4-x^2x^3),(x^1)^2+(x^3)^2-(x^2)^2-(x^4)^2)$. Now I want to compute $dF_p(v)$.

I think that the notation is confusing me, but I believe that $y^1(x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4)=2(x^1x^2+x^3x^4)$ and so on. Does $F^j$ represent the same thing as $y^j$? Because if that is the case then the computation would be pretty easy, I think that $\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}$ would just be the partial derivative but then what is $\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$? Also I believe that this is a sum right? The notation is weird but i think this is $\sum_j \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$. Would someone mind going through this example for me so I can explicitly see what each thing represents.

Comment: Here, you would need 2 coordinate functions $(y^1,y^2)$ which are defined on a certain open subset $V$ of $S^2$. The function $F^j$ is by definition $y^j\circ F$ (or to be really precise it is $y^j\circ (F|_{F^{-1}(V)\cap U})$, where $U$ is the domain of a coordinate chart on $S^3$). You seem to be making the grave sin of confusing coordinates on the ambient $\Bbb{R}^4,\Bbb{R}^3$ for coordinates on the spheres $S^3,S^2$.

Comment: If you want to compute in local coordinates then you must decide first and foremost, **which** local coordinates are you choosing on the domain and target? Note that there are several possible choices: common ones include graph coordinates, polar coordinates, sterographic projection coordinates etc. Each has advantages and disadvantages, but you need to decide before delving into computations. Btw, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4188549/568204) is a somewhat related question where OP made the same mistake as you are right now.

Comment: As peek-a-boo pointed out already: $S^3$ is a three-dimensional manifold and has as basis only three vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\,.$ You seem to think it has four but your Hopf map is expressed in coordinates of the ambient Euclidean space. Likewise $S^2$ has only two basis vector fields. You might have an easier life when you look at $M=N=\mathbb R^2$ and take as $F$ the coordinate transformation from Cartesian to polar coordinates.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think I understand, so I should be thinking of  $F$ taking $S^3$ to $S^2$ as taking $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ to $(y^1,y^2)$ right? Then use the atlases on  those spheres (which was done using stereographic projection) to do thing in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do you mind giving a basic example so that I can solidify this idea in my mind (maybe taking the cartesian to polar coordinates) as suggested by Kurt G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first technical exercise I think it is legit to view the map
$$
F:\begin{pmatrix}x^1\\x^2\\x^3\\x^4\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}(2(x^1x^2+x^3x^4)\\2(x^1x^4-x^2x^3)\\(x^1)^2+(x^3)^2-(x^2)^2-(x^4)^2\end{pmatrix}
$$
not as the Hopf map but as a map from $\mathbb R^4$ to $\mathbb R^3$ each equipped with their standard coordinate bases
$$
\Big\{
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\,,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\,,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}\,,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^4}\Big\}\,,\text{ resp. }
\Big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1}\,,\frac{\partial}{\partial y^2}\,,\frac{\partial}{\partial y^3}\Big\}\,.
$$
To answer your questions briefly in this case:
$$
\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}
$$
is the Jacobian of $F\,.$ Please calculate it.

$$\tag{1}
\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}
$$
is a sum
$$\tag{2}
\sum_{j=1}^3\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\,.
$$
(1) and (2) is a vector field on $\mathbb R^3$ and denoted by
$$
dF\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big)
$$
and also by
$$
F_*\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big)
$$
(which is called push forward of $\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$ by $F$).

Comment: Just as a technical question but will $\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}$ always be the Jacobian? My understanding is that $\partial$ in tangent spaces might not be the partial derivative that we are used to.

Comment: It will be the Jacobian of a function that you get once you have chosen coordinate charts. I do not want to elaborate on this further since this amounts to giving a lecture on differential geometry. Be patient, work with concrete examples and you will get there. The real Hopf map you should work with through your entire life. Have fun!

Comment: just another question but if I am asked to find a formula for $F$ in local coordinates, would that be the same as finding $\psi\circ F\circ \phi^-1$ where $\psi$ is my coordinate chat from $N$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi$ is from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$? Do local coordinates mean the coordinates in euclidean space or coordinates on the manifold?

Comment: With $\psi\circ F\circ \phi^{-1}$ you are getting close. That is a function from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$ and has a Jacobian. The coordinates are tuples in $\mathbb R^m\,,$ resp. in $\mathbb R^n$ by which we label points in $M$ resp. in $N\,.$  Coordinates *on* the manifold? Forget that.

Comment: @ Kurt G. So is that why we always consider things in terms of neighborhoods around points. Because then we can essentially consider a point of a manifold being the same thing as a  point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So in the case of the hopf map we are really just computing the differential of $\psi\circ F\circ \phi^{-1}$ since euclidean space and the manifold are essentially the same? Am I sort of understanding. Also the $y^i$ depend on the $x^i$ right?

Comment: I do not  want to say "right" here and let you move on with something else. The next fruitful exercise you may want to do is: choose coordinates for $S^2$ (most popular are spherical $(\theta,\varphi)$) and for $S^3$ (spherical or quaternions). Then calculate $dF$ for the real Hopf map. Getting into rabbit holes is healthy. Not asking questions like manifold and $\mathbb R^n$ are "essentially" the same.